# Entitiy Framework/Database Decimal issue

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, decimal

In my project I have a field in the database that was a Decimal(10,3). It was recently decided that it should allow 4 spots after the decimal so I modified the field to be a Decimal(11,4). For some reason the fourth decimal spot never saves. I traced through my code and I can see the entity property gets set to "1.2345" for example but the value that is showing in the database is "1.2340".

I can't figure out why my last decimal spot is not saving. As far as I can tell my entity framework edmx doesn't have a set number of decimal places (precision is set to none) and if I manually change the value in the database it will store a non-zero number in the 4th decimal spot. After doing so the correct value gets pulled out of the database (through entity framework) and displayed in my project.

Any ideas on where to look to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete and insert the entity again, sometimes it's needed to get updates

Comment: I'm sure that would have fixed it too. I opened up the edmx in a text editor and found the field. It did have settings for precision so I updated those to the new settings. I'm sure if I deleted/added the entity again it would get the new values too.